# Java getBytes() method is stripping .00 from numbers in my String

Tags: java, csv

I'm generating a csv file and I have a bunch of numbers without decimal points and I'm being required to put .00 for those cases, I'm using:

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

So fa so good I can see a string looking this way:

```
String myStringWithDecimalPoints = "124.00, 24567868.00, 5.00"
```

but when I do:

```
out.write(myStringWithDecimalPoints.getBytes());
```

I get in my csv:

```
124, 24567868, 5
```

Why is this happening?

Any workarounds? (it does have to be CSV and .00 must appear)

Comment: Are you looking at your CSV in plain text or in spreadsheet?

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?  (Because I can't: http://ideone.com/Zn7gxi)

Comment: Can you show how your OutputStream (I assume that's what `out` is) is created? It's typically better to user a PrintWriter for Strings so that the character encoding isn't mangled.

Comment: Are you sure your original string is being changed?  What happens when you System.out.println(); your string?  It sounds like you are using a formatter to affect how your string is output in some cases.  But that does not necessarily mean your original string is being changed, without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the character encoding. Better to show a more detailed code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my answer ... I was opening it with Excel ... Excel was hiding those decimal points when I open it in Sublime it shows the decimal points... can you post it as an answer so I can accept it @Sotirios Delimanolis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful with how you view your data, especially in spreadsheets like Excel where the format of the output depends on the type of the cell. It may or may not show decimal values.

A note for the future, with a call like

```
out.write(myStringWithDecimalPoints.getBytes());
```

you can safely assume that Java is writing all the bytes to the `OutputStream`. If you're not seeing the same thing in the receiving side, then the receiving isn't being done like you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is some confusion between the value of your original string, and how your string appears when you output it in certain ways using your formatter.  This does not necessarily mean that your "original" string has been altered.

We could say with greater certainty if you provided a more complete code example.